# Selected text color in the JFace tree

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface

I'm preparing Eclipse editor where one of the tabs is a tree with some values. I'm using colors and font style to give more information for the user. E.g. when the user puts a value which is out of range then the font color is red, or when a value is non-default then the font has a bold style.

But the user has to move the selection to another cell to see if the color/style has changed or not. **Is it possible to change the color/style of the selected cell in the JFace tree?**

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. The two most obvious are:

- Add your own custom label provider. Example [here](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/plain/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet050DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.java).
- Add a label decorator. [Here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Decorators/decorators.html) is a older somewhat dated article.

It is not possible to change the colors via theming.